# Data Associations in Node using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

When creating models in NODE using MYSQL, how does one write the relationships between Users and Products for example. How do you show there is an association. Do you not need to show association when writing the Models and just use Join in the SQL query?

Comment: You could theoretically use ORM like [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) and make use out of [relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations)... Remember that js variables are just objects, so if you get back already `JOINED` data, then you will get `JOINED` object.

Comment: What if you don't want to use an ORM like Prisma or Sequelize? Is it necessary to create model schemas for MVC pattern for MYSQL?

Comment: Well, as I said before, If your SQL query returns already JOINED data, then you get already JOINED javascript object.